# Traveling down a highway at near light speed

Tags: special-relativity

I’ve read that while traveling in space closer and closer to the speed of light everything I would be observing and I would see other people or things moving more slowly.

I’m having a hard time internalizing this concept. Because when I am on the highway the faster I go of course the faster it seems the trees or other cars go past me. With the ideas of special relativity, if I approached the speed of light and were passing these trees I know I could say that I am staying still and the trees are moving at whatever velocity and that their clocks are moving slow, but does that mean they still zip past me quite quickly (ignoring Doppler effects so that I could still see them) and the trees are just aging in slow motion? Or would everything around me be moving slowly past me too?

Comment: You're right. Stuff zips by you very quickly, but those clocks seem to be ticking slow compared to your clock. And because of symmetry, they think that *your* clock is ticking slow compared to theirs. In relativity, we always need to carefully distinguish between what we see, and what we measure after we account for the fact that stuff is zipping by and the time it takes for light to travel from the stuff we're looking at.

Comment: Stuff can pass by you fast and be frozen at the same time.

Comment: Here is an animated simulation showing the situation you're asking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQnHTKZBTI4